# which is the best way to check that an array is empty

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to know if an array is empty, as I am still learning to use php I would like to know which is the best way .. now I am doing it this way:

```
if (sizeof($myarray) == 0) { }
```

Comment: [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: Sounds opinionated though

Comment: @Akintunde: Maybe, maybe not, kind of like _"which is best way to check size of array"_ ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the variable exists, then

```
if (!$myarray) { }
```

is probably the simplest, amount-of-code-wise. ([Empty arrays evaluate as false.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)) If you're not sure whether or not it exists, then

```
if (empty($myarray)) { }
```

will avoid undefined variable notices as well.

Counting it is unnecessary work if all you need is to see whether or not it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) is the best way:

> empty — Determine whether a variable is empty

```
if (empty($myarray)) {}
```